# Issue: TMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, flutter, deprecated

I received an alert from IOS Apple Store.
But I never used UIWebView code. 
My flutter version is "Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.737], locale en-US)".

And My pubspec.yaml code is...

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.6.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  camera: ^0.4.2
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.2+1
  html: ^0.14.0+2
  url_launcher: ^5.1.3
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  vibration: 1.2.1
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39470#issuecomment-534523104) in Github. Since you are not using `google_sign_in` you can easily fix this problem with command `cd ios && pod update --repo-update`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it.